# Different people in Java development team using same Java Code Style Formatter file but still formatting varies in terms of space

Tags: eclipse, format, formatter, eclipse-jdt

Different people in Java development team are using same Java Code Style Formatter file but still formatting varies in terms of space. 
Lets say if I have made one change in a file after saving it (which automatically does import and format) I find 10 difference (1 actual change and 9 space changes at different 9 line) while comparing with latest file from repository which makes harder to see what exactly you have changed.

Have anyone faced this issue before or suggest some solution to this problem?

Team is using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Indigo Service Release 2.

Comment: Could there be differences in the preferred line delimiter of files? Carriage Return and Line Feed rather than just Line Feed?

Comment: Not possible as we are using single formatter file which was imported into eclipse from same location. So file is exactly same.

Comment: This is not something you control using the formatting preferences. It could be the setting on the `Workspace` preference page, it could be a source control tool trying to be "helpful." Have you set the `Compare/Patch` preference page to ignore white space?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked through some extent. I noticed that line break is coming differently in code among different team members, again they are using the same formatter file.

Comment: Few team members have different eclipse versions, that might be an issue I reckon.